# Como puede determinar si un Array está o no ordenado?

Tags: vb.net

Quiero saber si un array esta o no ordenado con Visual Basic, lo estoy intentando hacer con una variable boleana, si entra en alguna condición que determine si es o no un array ordenado... lo que llevo es esto:

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
    Dim numbers = New Integer() {2, 1, 5, 0,23,3}
    Dim lista() As Integer = New Integer((10) - 1) {}

    Dim res = New Integer() {}
    Dim ordenado As Boolean 
    ordenado = true

    For index As Integer = 0  To numbers.Length -1
          Console.WriteLine(" es:  " & numbers(index))
    Next

    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

no se mucho de VB, pero se me ocurre guardar tu arreglo en otro, y luego arreglar uno y comparar, asa sabrías si esta o no arreglado, por el momento puedo ayudarte en eso, igual puede que alguien pueda hacerlo mejor, o te de una idea.

Uso esta parte para guardar temporalmente el arreglo

```
Dim temp_numbers() As Integer
For index As Integer = 0  To numbers.Length -1
    ReDim Preserve temp_numbers(index)
    temp_numbers(index) = (numbers(index))
Next
```

Luego uso el método burbuja para ordenar uno.

```
Dim Count As Integer = 0
Dim Swapvalue As Integer
For ii As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
    For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
        Count += 1
        If numbers(i) > numbers(i + 1) Then
            Swapvalue = numbers(i)
            numbers(i) = numbers(i + 1)
            numbers(i + 1) = Swapvalue
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Finalmente comparo, teniendo como codigo final el siguiente.

```
Module VBModule
    Sub Main()
    Dim numbers = New Integer() {2, 1, 5, 0,23,3}
    Dim temp_numbers() As Integer
    For index As Integer = 0  To numbers.Length -1
            ReDim Preserve temp_numbers(index)
           temp_numbers(index) = (numbers(index))
    Next
    Dim lista() As Integer = New Integer((10) - 1) {}

    Dim res = New Integer() {}
    Dim ordenado As Boolean 
    ordenado = true
    
        Dim Count As Integer = 0
        Dim Swapvalue As Integer
        For ii As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
            For i As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
                Count += 1
                If numbers(i) > numbers(i + 1) Then
                    Swapvalue = numbers(i)
                    numbers(i) = numbers(i + 1)
                    numbers(i + 1) = Swapvalue
                End If
            Next
        Next
        
        For index As Integer = 0  To temp_numbers.Length -1
          If numbers(index) <> temp_numbers(index)
              ordenado=false
          End If        
        Next
        
        Console.WriteLine("Ordenado ? :  " & ordenado)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero si en caso fuera un array de tipo Strng?
   Dim myArray = new String() {"a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c", "b", "a"}
     Dim n As Integer = 8